# easy_install with various versions of python installed, mac osx

Tags: python, macos, macports

I have various versions of python on a mac OSX 10.6 machine, some of them installed with macports:

```
> python_select -l
Available versions:
current none python24 python26 python26-apple python27
```

The default or system version is `python26-apple`. I am now using python27, which I selected with

```
> sudo python_select python27
```

I recently tried installing django using `easy_install`, but it got installed with the default python (I can check that by python_selecting python26-apple and importing django). If, instead, I download the django tarball, expand and use

```
> sudo python setup.py install
```

everything works as expected, i.e. I get django in python 2.7. Now the question is, is there a way to get `easy_install` to work with the version of python I have selected with `python_select`?

**UPDATE** Apparently `python_select` is deprecated. The following command seems to be equivalent:

```
port select --list python
```

producing:

```
Available versions for python:
    none
    python24
    python26
    python26-apple
    python27 (active)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want your "easy_install" match your updated python version, follow these steps:

Download the corresponding .egg file at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#files
Run it as if it were a shell script: sh setuptools-0.6c9-py2.7.egg
This will install the new "easy_install" executable, compatible with your current version of python.

Hope this helps.

(more details at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#cygwin-mac-os-x-linux-other)

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine. The only glitch was that I had to add `script-dir /usr/bin` to get the new easy_install in the PATH. Also, if I select python26-apple again, I have to remember to use `easy_install-2.6` since `easy_install` is now bound to python 2.7. But I can live with that!

Comment: i am sad to find out that this is the way to get easy_install-2.7 onto an Amazon Linux instance. Would have been nicer to yum install it.

Comment: that's not easy at all!

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to use the -prefix= option on that shell script to control where your easy_install version lands.