# Install python module to non default version of python on Mac

Tags: python, module

I have a couple different versions of Python installed on my Mac. The default version is 2.5, so when I install a module it gets installed to 2.5. I need to be able to install some modules to a different version of Python because I am working on projects that use different versions. Any one know how to accomplish this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: For a similar question, on installing modules with `easy_install` when different versions of python, installed with macports ara available, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792060/easy-install-with-various-versions-of-python-installed-mac-osx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're installing using setup.py, just run it via the appropriate version of Python, e.g.:

```
python2.6 setup.py install
```

If you're using easy_install there should be a version for the corresponding Python version called easy_install-N.N, e.g.

```
easy_install-2.6 some_module
```

If you're working on different projects that require different versions of Python, consider using [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) (and [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/)) - it allows you to fire up and use multiple environments each with its own version of Python and set of libraries. Example usage would be something like:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.5.4
$ mkvirtualenv --python=python2.6 foo
foo $ python -V
Python 2.6.1
foo $ pip install some_mod # installs module in foo's library, rather
                           # than site wide
foo $ deactivate # leave the virtual env
$ python -m some_mod
/path/to/python: No module named some_mod
```

To go back to the foo environment later, use `workon`:

```
$ workon foo
foo $ python -m some_mod # no error, apns available within the env
foo $
```

So you can use virtualenv to maintain separate environments for each version of Python you have installed. Within those environments, pip and easy_install just do the right thing.

Comment: How exactly do you get the version of easy_install that you need?  None of the stuff I've ready is easy or points me to something that works.

Comment: Ok, apparently the package name is `setuptools` not `easy_install`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're installing through setuptools (ie `python setup.py`), it will install to the lib directory for the python executable you use (unless it's a broken package).

Answer (score 2):

If you've installed them using [macports](/questions/tagged/macports) then you run (as root):

```
port select --set python <python_version>
```

**Hint:** To list available versions run:

```
port select --list python
```

---

Otherwise you can set the `$PYTHON_PATH` environment variable and add your desired [python](/questions/tagged/python) path to your `$PATH` environment variable as well.

You will also need to update the `python.current` (or something with similar name) symbolic link in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`.

---

I strongly recommend to install all the versions using a package manager ([homebrew](/questions/tagged/homebrew), [macports](/questions/tagged/macports), [fink](/questions/tagged/fink), etc.) so they'll be easier to manage.

Comment: `port install python_select` seems to proceed okay, but there is no `python_select` binary afterwards...

Comment: `python_select` is deprecated. Do `sudo port select --set python <python_version> (ex. python26)` instead.