# Install python module to non default version of python using .sh

Tags: python, installation, centos, python-install

I have a problem similar to this post: [Install python module to non default version of python on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220274/install-python-module-to-non-default-version-of-python-on-mac), so I am aware of those solutions, but they do not work for me.

I am installing M2Crypto on CentOS, which means I much use `fedora_setup.sh build` followed by `fedora_setup.sh install` in order to install on my architecture.

Unfortunately, the default Python version is 2.6, but I use 2.7.  How do I execute the build and install commands so that they build and install to Python2.7 site-packages?  Is there a simple command I don't know?  I've been searching around here: http://docs.python.org/2/install/ in the Python Docs, but I don't see anything about .sh scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an incredibly difficult answer to come by, but the support team at Webfaction where I am hosted were spectacular in assisting me.  Directly from the support I was given:

First build swig,

```
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/swig/swig-2.0.8.tar.gz
tar -xf swig-2.0.8.tar.gz 
cd swig-2.0.8
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make
make install
```

Than get m2crypto,

```
svn checkout http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/tags/0.21/ m2crypto-0.21
cd m2crypto-0.21/
```

Edit fedora_setup.sh from this

```
SWIG_FEATURES=-cpperraswarn python setup.py $*
```

to this,

```
SWIG_FEATURES=-cpperraswarn python2.7 setup.py $*
```

Then build, then install,

```
./fedora_setup.sh build
./fedora_setup.sh install --prefix=$HOME

[me@web342 lib]$ python2.7
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 16 2013, 20:16:09) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import M2Crypto
>>> print M2Crypto
<module 'M2Crypto' from '/home/me/lib/python2.7/site-packages/M2Crypto-0.21-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/M2Crypto/__init__.pyc'>
```

Obviously, substitute your own details throughout.  Hope this helps the next guy trying to install M2Crytpo using fedora_setup to a non-default python version.

Answer (score 0):

You should run your scripts in a [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) created for your app's environment. This creates an isolated environment that uses the Python interpreter you created the virtualenv with, but with its own set of libraries.

```bash
# create the virtualenv folder: M2Crypto-venv
python2.7 virtualenv.py --distribute M2Crypto-venv

# activate the virtualenv, changing environment variables to use its Python interpreter
. M2Crypto-venv/bin/activate

# see how the current python has changed
which python        # should be M2Crypto-venv/bin/python
python --version    # should be 2.7

# after activating, run your install scripts
```

If you're using mod_wsgi or something similar to serve content, you'll want to modify your WSGI file to activate the virtualenv before doing anything else (adapted from [mod_wsgi instructions](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments)):

```
import os.path

virtualenv_path = '/path/to/M2Crypto-venv'
activate_this = os.path.join(virtualenv_path, 'bin/activate_this.py')
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__ = activate_this))

# rest of the WSGI file...
```

Comment: Will the rest of my project be able to access the resources installed in the virtualenv?  IF Django can't talk to M2Crypto, then it defeats the purpose for me.  Will I be able to just add the virtualenv to the Python Path or something?

Comment: You should install Django and the other project components in the virtualenv as well. After you've activated, the virtualenv `pip` can do that for you.

Comment: If you're using mod_wsgi or something similar to serve content, you'll want to modify your WSGI file to activate the virtualenv before doing anything else (config added to original post)

Comment: Hrm, I already have the site all but completely setup, so this wouldn't be ideal.  If there is no other solution, I suppose I can do all the work to make this happen, but I'd prefer to just install to the "real" python2.7 if I can.

Comment: @fildred13: virtualenvs take a few extra minutes to set up, but are *wonderful* for isolating different apps with different dependencies on the same server. We use this capability frequently where I work - not all apps run on the same version of Django, for example.

Comment: Okay, I'll do some reading and see if it is a good solution for me.  But M2Crypto works in Python2.7, as it is functioning on my development server now.  So if it isn't a dependency problem, why should I use a dependency solution?