# How to use pip on a python by path?

Tags: python, macos, pip

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220274/install-python-module-to-non-default-version-of-python-on-mac) shows how to use pip for different python versions.  However, I have the same version of python installed in two different paths.  Let's not ask why, if I remove one, things break.

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python -c "import sys; print sys.version"
2.7.10 (default, Jun 10 2015, 19:42:47) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)]
$ /usr/bin/python -c "import sys; print sys.version"
2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)]
```

pip seems to install packages to /usr/local/bin/python.

How do I install a package to /usr/bin/python?

I'm on OS X, Yosemite (10.10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two python installations you can have two pips.

Install a pip for the other python:

```
sudo /usr/bin/python -m easy_install pip
```

Execute pip as a module:

```
/usr/bin/python -m pip install --user your_package
```

Recommend to symlink them to separate names.

Comment: Thank you!  But "/usr/bin/python: No module named pip"

Comment: P.s. do you know about [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) ?

Comment: This worked! Both pip-s seem to be living together somehow.

Comment: It's normal.  And in fact very common to have `pip` and `pip3` on the same system.

Comment: Can't use virtualenv, I want to try using it from R (rPython). I understand how f-ed up this seems.

Answer (score 0):

you could :

1. update your PATH variable to give priority to /usr/bin/python over /usr/local/bin/python
2. call pip by its full path:

   /usr/bin/pip install package

[EDIT] pip seems not to be present on /usr/bin on Yosemite, so you should use easy_install instead

```
/usr/bin/easy_install package
```

Comment: Thanks! pip has a shebang (#!) of the wrong python. Then, when I try executing it directly (/usr/bin/python `which pip` install package), the right python complains it doesn't know pip exists. I'm afraid to easy-install for /usr/bin/python for fear pip will freak out.

Comment: If you have two installations of python, you can/should have two installations of pip.  Trying to use the same version of pip for multiple python versions will be a world of pain ..

Comment: This might have worked, but I got the other one to work, so off I go. Thanks.