# pip install for Multiple Python Distributions on Mac

Tags: python, macos, pip, easy-install

I am fine having multiple distributions of Python on my system, given the advice found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218891/multiple-versions-of-python-on-os-x-leopard).

However: I cannot get `easy_install` nor `pip install` to install to the distribution associated with `/usr/bin/python` on Mac. They will only install modules to the distribution associated with `/Library/Python/2.6/`.

This is a problem because both my default `python` calls and XCode compiles are associated with `/usr/bin/python`.

So, for example, when I try to `pip install appscript`, I get back a cheeky

`Requirements already satisfied`

But, then, when I open up `python` or XCode and try to `import appscript`, I get

`ImportError: No module named appscript`

How do I force `pip` to install to whatever distribution is associated with `/usr/bin/python`?

Comment: I have multiple pip scripts: pip (default python), pip-2.6, pip-2.7 etc... I'm on Gentoo though.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792060/easy-install-with-various-versions-of-python-installed-mac-osx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that `easy_install` (and `pip`) was not associated with Python 2.7 (the version used by my default `python` and XCode). Per [vartec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60711/vartec)'s instructions on an Answer that has now been deleted, I downloaded and installed `easy_install` for the correct version of python:

`sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg`

(`easy_install` is part of `setuptools`)

After doing this, my default call to `easy_install` suddenly switched to installing packages for the distribution used by `python` and XCode.

Both `python` and XCode have access to `appscript` now, so whatever, I guess. Thanks for the help everyone, especially [vartec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60711/vartec).

Comment: Also note that you may need to reinstall pip in order for the setuptools changes to take effect, and for new pip-installed modules to appear in the python scope.

Comment: Another way is to get a fresh https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and run it with your particular python binary, i.e. `/sw/bin/python2.7` and that will give you an alternate pip for that version of Python.

Answer (score 1):

You should invoke the correct version of easy_install or pip. One way to do that is set the the version you want to work with on your path:

```
 export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:$PATH
```

This works for `easy_install`. For `pip`, you need to give the python environment to the `pip` command:

```
pip install -E /Library/Python/2.6/ appscript
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. You say I need to invoke the correct version of *pip* but then give me instructions for changing the path to *python*. Wouldn't that still be using the same version of pip? I'm a little wary about modifying my path without knowing exactly what you are talking about..

Comment: @Chris: both `easy_install` and `pip` are Python scripts, and their settings depend on Python interpreter used

Comment: I appreciate the offer of advice, rafalotufo, but this ultimately was not the solution that worked.

Comment: The -E is not a valid argument flag for pip in my machine running OS 10.8.2