# Error when running tests of scipy and numpy on OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: python, numpy, osx-snow-leopard, scipy, nose

I am new to stackoverflow as well as Python, and I hope to use stackoverflow to learn and improve my Python programming.

However, as soon as I set up Python, SciPy, NumPy on my Mac, I encountered a problem when I tried running a full test of SciPy and NumPy to verify the install:

```
>>> import scipy
>>> scipy.test()
Running unit tests for scipy

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    scipy.test()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/nosetester.py", line 318, in test
    self._show_system_info()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/nosetester.py", line 187, in _show_system_info
    nose = import_nose()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/nosetester.py", line 69, in import_nose
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Need nose >= 0.10.0 for tests - see http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose
```

As suggested by the error message, I install this 'nose' package via easy_install, and the install seems successful as I get the following from bash:

```
mlstr:~ mlstr$ nosetests -V
nosetests version 1.1.2
```

So I tried the SciPy test again, and it failed with the same message. Can someone please let me know if I need to do anything else to install/configure nose so that it can be used by the unit tests of SciPy and NumPy. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE #1**: After trying Rahul's suggestion of using pip to reinstall nose, I think I've found where the problem is: whenever I do easy_install or pip from bash, the package is installed into   Python 2.6 directories instead of 2.7 ones. And I think this is because by default 2.6 is the one shipped with Snow Leopard. So what should I do to tell easy_install  or pip that I want to install a particular package for Python 2.7? Thanks.

**UPDATE #2**: By following up my update above, I've found the solution here: [easy_install with various versions of python installed, mac osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792060/easy-install-with-various-versions-of-python-installed-mac-osx). It is indeed because that I used the wrong version of easy_install thus my nose installation was for Python 2.6 shipped with Mac OS X. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I tried replicating the error that you were encountering. I did not have nose, so I was getting the same error.

I installed nose using pip

> > sudo pip install nose

After that the scipy.test() worked. I did nothing else. Did you install nose using pip? If not, try using pip.

My machine has : 
SciPy version 0.10.0.dev
Nose - 1.1.2

Comment: I installed nose via easy_install, would that make any difference? Is there any way I can verify my nose installation? thanks.

Comment: @MLister To verify if you have *nose* installed `import nose` should not through an exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your locally installed python version you need to make sure, that this is called when you run python from console.

On a linux machine an alias would do that. Once you run the correct python from your console all the easy_install things will be available in the correct python version.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I have updated my original question to include a solution.