# Zope installed to wrong version (easy_install and pip)

Tags: python, macos, twisted, zope, egg

I downloaded the python egg for zope.interface version 4.0.5 and tried to install it with easy_install and then pip. Both installed it to python 2.7, which is the default on my computer. Is there any way to install it to python3?

I'm on Mac OSX 10.8.3. I've looked around for some solution, but the only one I found with this problem was here: [easy_install with various versions of python installed, mac osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792060/easy-install-with-various-versions-of-python-installed-mac-osx), but the answer doesn't work.

Comment: You need to use the correct `easy_install` script; the one you used is the one installed with 2.7. How did you install Python 3?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest installing the [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) package manager, and installing python 3 with it.

#### Installing Homebrew:

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"`

#### Installing Python 3

`brew install python3`

- Pip for Python 3 would be installed as pip3 by the above command.
- `easy_install` is depretiated with homebrew, and you don't need to use `sudo` with `pip3` or `gem`

> Note, easy_install is deprecated. We install pip (or pip3 for python3) along with python/python3.

[source](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Gems%2C-Eggs-and-Perl-Modules#with-a-brewed-python--you-dont-need-sudo)

Comment: That doesn't tell the OP *anything* about how to use easy_install to install additional packages into Python 3. For all we know the OP **already** installed Python 3 with howebrew.

Comment: @MartijnPieters good point, filled in information about how `pip3` would be auto installed, and that `easy_install` is deprecated.

Comment: I'd not call `easy_install` deprecated; it may be that homebrew sees it that way. `pip` is, in most ways, better, so it's a minor point.