# easy_install and Macports on Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, macports, easy-install

I saw an answer to this question here [easy_install with various versions of python installed, mac osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792060/easy-install-with-various-versions-of-python-installed-mac-osx) but it doesn't install easy install with my version of python. When I run port select --list python I get the following list:
    none
    python25-apple
    python26-apple
    python27 (active)
    python27-apple

My problem is that no matter how I edit my path, everything is still installed using /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin instead /opt/local/bin/python. I am not sure how to resolve this. I tried using virtualenv but that can't be installed due to missing pip etc.

Edit: I am not trying to install pip using macports. The problem is that the python I am using is the python installed via macports and when I am trying to install anything using easyinstall, it is using apple version of python. For example, I installed python eve using easy_install, but when I invoke my python it's not working

Answer (score 0):

port is just one package manager for mac osx.  it is not necessary to use it for installing pip/etc.

http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html

use the full path to the python bin you want to use when invoking python

once complete edit your path accordingly (prioritizing the python version you want to use)

Comment: when I run /opt/local/bin/python get-pip.py  it gives me the following message Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg     

Afer that, when I run pip install eve it says pip command not found

Comment: try this `which python` i bet it's not the path you expect...now type `export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH` and then `pip install eve` (although you should use virtualenv!)

Comment: this is not working. which python returns opt/local/bin/python

Comment: export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin

is what is in my profile

Comment: `/opt/local/bin` needs to be in front if that's where python is (the one you want), edit your profile....although it sounds like you might want to point to: `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin`

Comment: Not working. I install pip using easy install but when I try to use it, it says pip not found. No idea what is happening

Comment: if pip is actually installed, then it's not in any of the directories in your path.  try `sudo find / -name pip` to find pip anywhere on your whole machine.  if it's there you need to add the directory to the path.  if it's not you need to install it.  stay aware of your path and which directory you're actually calling these commands from (/usr/bin, /usr/local/bin, /opt/local/bin...etc)